# Want to show last used values in Android text field

Tags: android

Is there a way to display the values that were last entered values into an EditText field?  I currently am able to save the last entered values to my database and pre-populate the last used value into the field itself but I would like to show the list of values underneath the field when it is clicked on.

Comment: Question not clear. You are able to display the last used value... then what is the issue?

Comment: I'd like to show the last 5 used values in a selectable list format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the last entered values to a persistant data storage (like you use database.. or sharedpreferences).

Use a Spinner instead of EditText http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Comment: Not sure if it works. If you use a `Spinner`, it will forever be empty, since the user will be unable to enter any text that would get recorded as history.

Comment: @CommonsWare . You have a point. The Spinner will never be populated. I think he has to create a new Class interited from TextView

Comment: Interesting idea but combining an EditText and Spinner into a custom UI element is a bit out of scope on this project.

Comment: Well.. You could always have a EditText and a Spinner closeby. So user can either select from Spinner or type in EditText. If the user selects from Spinner, populate the value in EditText (So that the Event handling for business logic can be done in one place .. in EditText). Alternatively, you could use an AutocompleteTextView, but prefix all your entries with same 1-2 letter code .. and somehow force the user (through texthint or error message or toast) to enter these two letters so that they will be able to see the history .. which they can decide to ignore or accept)

Comment: I suppose I'll have to create the custom UI element or combine the text box with a spinner.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [`AutoCompleteTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Comment: Not sure if it works. AutoCompleteTextView requires a minimum number of userentered chars to be typed before the dropdown list appears. And you cannot set it to zero . See doco .../AutoCompleteTextView.html#setThreshold%28int%29

Comment: @GSree: OTOH, there's nothing closer in Android.

Comment: Yeah understand that.. But the list in the AutoCompleteView may never popup. eg. If the history is say list of planets.. (and the setThreshold is set to 1), if the user enters J it will come with Jupiter only even if the last 5 selections included a few other planets.

Comment: Maybe textwatcher + initial space character and trim() at one text changed